# I am looking to add a navigation bar with title to tutorial I am following

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, titlebar

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var emojis = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "✈️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "⛵️", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
    
    @State var emojiCount = 20
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 65))]) {
                    ForEach(emojis[0..<emojiCount], id: \.self) { emoji in
                        CardView(content: emoji).aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
                    }
                }
            }
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                remove
                Spacer()
                add
                
            }
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    var remove: some View {
        Button {
            if emojiCount > 1 {
                emojiCount -= 1
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
        }
    }
    var add: some View {
        Button {
            if emojiCount < emojis.count {
                emojiCount += 1
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
        }
    }
    
}



struct CardView: View {
    var content: String
    @State var isFaceUp: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
            if isFaceUp {
                shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
               shape.strokeBorder(lineWidth: 3.0)
                Text(content).font(.largeTitle)
            } else {
                shape.fill()
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isFaceUp = !isFaceUp
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Adding a navigation bar and title is a pretty common task in SwiftUI. What have you tried so far? Did you try something you found that didn't work for you?

Comment: Yes, I am extremely new to coding. I have tried inserting navigation view and Navigation title but neither worked. I also just tried adding text to the top but that didn't work either. My issue I believe is the placement of the code.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? Looking at some tutorials might help, too: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/216/complete-guide-to-navigationview-in-swiftui

Comment: Yes I have been watching them but when I try to place what they show it doesn't work with the code I already have.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you getting any errors? What guide are you following?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the VStack to a NavigationView and then set the navigationTitle to it?

Maybe something like this should work:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 65))]) {
                    ForEach(emojis[0..<emojiCount], id: \.self) { emoji in
                        CardView(content: emoji).aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
                    }
                }
            }
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                remove
                Spacer()
                add
                
            }
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Title here!")
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```